# Как правильно: "стороны света" или "страны света"?

Tags: фразеология

По словарю Ожегова и Шведовой - *страны* (в значении 'местность, территория'). Хотя привычнее - *стороны* (субъективно, конечно).

Нет ошибка ли здесь в словаре?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ПОЧИТАЕМ ИСТОЧНИКИ

1. У ОЖЕГОВА: ВОСТОК 1. Одна из четырех стран света.
2. ВИКИПЕДИЯ: В географии сторона света — одно из четырёх основных направлений (север, юг, запад, восток).
3. ЭНЦИКЛОПЕДИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ: Страны Света - (стороны горизонта) - четыре главные ТОЧКИ горизонта: север, юг (, восток (), запад . Иногда странами света называют соответствующие ЧЕТВЕРТИ горизонта.
4. ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЯ 
   СТРАНА. ◊ Страна света (устар.) — то же, что часть света. — Ну, путешествуй дальше. Али уже все пересчитал страны света? Помяловский.
5. ТЕКСТЫ: Каждый обучающийся должен научиться определять стороны горизонта по компасу.

ПОПРОБУЕМ СДЕЛАТЬ ВЫВОД

1. Возможные варианты: сторона или страна, точка или направление, страна (сторона) света или горизонта.
2. В современном языке активно применяется понятие «сторона света»,  но более точным термином в профессиональной речи является выражение «сторона горизонта».
3. «Страны света»  в прежнем значении - понятие устаревающее. С одной стороны,  страны света заменили частями света, а с другой – сторонами света или горизонта. А по странам света (различным государствам) можно просто путешествовать.

Answer (score 2):

Этимология по Максу Фасмеру: 
Страна - происходит от церк.-слав. "страна" вместо исконного "сторона"(ра//оро). Сюда же странник, др.-русск. стороньникъ — то же, ст.-слав. страньникъ (др.греч. xenos (незнакомец)), а также странный — ст.-слав. страньнъ (xenos). 
 Во всех толковых и этимологических словарях – аналогично.

Термины СТРАНА и СТОРОНА   фиксируются практически  одновременно, слово СТРАНА использовалось в церковной литературе, как церковнославянизм,а СТОРОНА применялось в обычной деловой лексике; со временем они расходятся (обрастают новыми значениями).

Слово СТОРОНА в значениях, указанных для термина СТРАНА употребляется преимущественно в СЛУЖЕБНЫХ документах (деловые грамоты, указы, распоряжения),морские документы тоже- "сторона света" . Очень редко в СМЫСЛЕ  "государство, страна"- как разговорное и диалектное. А вот государство - СТРАНА от исходного значения " 1) Место по правую или по левую руку лежащее; 2) Область, государство" ( Словарь Академии Российской 1789 г. )Значение " Один из четырех концов света" там на третьем месте как нераспространённое, видимо, оно уже начинает уходить из светской литературы в духовную.